# No Hibernate Session bound to thread exception using asp mvc 3, nhibernate 3.2 and spring.net 1.3.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, spring.net

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 3, spring.net 1.3.2 and nhibernate 3.2. I've been struggling to get the web application to run in IIS 7.5. It works fine inside Visual Studio 2010.

The error I'm getting is

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: NHibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here]
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.SpringSessionContext.CurrentSession() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate12\Data\NHibernate\SpringSessionContext.cs:72
   Technolog.Rma.Business.Repositories.RepairBatchDAO.findRepairBatchPageCount(String login, Int32 rowsPerPage) in C:\work\samplemvc\src\Technolog.Rma.Business\Repositories\RepairBatchDAO.cs:55
   _dynamic_Technolog.Rma.Business.Repositories.RepairBatchDAO.findRepairBatchPageCount(Object , Object[] ) +273
   Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeMethod.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicMethod.cs:156
   Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicMethodInvocation.InvokeJoinpoint() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\DynamicMethodInvocation.cs:100
   Spring.Dao.Support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data\Dao\Support\PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.cs:181

<snip/>
```

My web.config file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368

  Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core

    <resource uri="~/Config/propertyConfigurer.xml" />
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.MvcContextHandler, Spring.Web.Mvc3" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="dataFile" value="App_Data\data.db3" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="SessionFactory"/>
  </appSettings>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/propertyConfigurer.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/sessionFactory.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/mappers.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/repositories.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/controllers.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/scopedobjects.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/utils.xml" />
    </context>
  </spring>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <!--
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/> 
      -->
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
    <handlers>
      <add name="SpringPageHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="SpringWebServiceHandler" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="SpringContextMonitor" verb="*" path="ContextMonitor.ashx" type="Spring.Web.Support.ContextMonitor, Spring.Web"/>
    </handlers>
    -->
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.7.0" newVersion="4.0.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My sessionFactory.xml file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" 
         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx">

  <object
    id="siteRoot"
    type="System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment, System.Web"
    factory-method="get_ApplicationPhysicalPath" />

  <object
    id="dataFile"
    type="System.IO.Path, mscorlib"
    factory-method="Combine">
    <constructor-arg name="path1" ref="siteRoot" />
    <constructor-arg name="path2" value="${dataFile}" />
  </object>

  <db:provider id="dbProvider"
               provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
               connectionString="Data Source=AJASQL7;Initial Catalog=Xanadu;User ID=RMA;Password=RMA;"/>


  <object id="sessionFactory" scope="application" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingAssemblies">
      <list>
        <value>Technolog.Rma.Business</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
      <dictionary>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql7Dialect"/>
        <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
        <entry key="use_proxy_validator" value="false" />
        <entry key="current_session_context_class" value="Spring.Data.NHibernate.SpringSessionContext, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/>
      </dictionary>
    </property>

  </object>

  <!-- Transaction Management Strategy - local database transactions -->

  <object id="transactionManager"
        type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </object>

  <!-- Exception translation object post processor -->
  <object type="Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, Spring.Data"/>

</objects>
```

Part of my  RepairBatchDao is

```
[Repository]
class RepairBatchDAO : IRepairBatchDAO
{

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    public long findRepairBatchPageCount(string login, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        var rowCount = 1L;
        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); // line 55
        var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
            var hqlCountQuery = session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Technolog.Rma.Business.Domain.RepairBatch rb where rb.Customer.Login=?")
                            .SetParameter(0, login);
            rowCount = hqlCountQuery.UniqueResult<long>();
            transaction.Commit();
            return (rowCount + rowsPerPage - 1) / rowsPerPage;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (session != null) session.Close(); // I shouldn't be doing this...
        }

        return 0L;

    }

    // snip ...
```

I've spent too much time trying to fix this myself. I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. I've checked various posts in stackoverflow (too many to mention) but they haven't helped.

I'm a Java guy and this is my first .net project so aren't sure whether I've done anything silly.

25/9/2012

I've made changes to my customerDAO

```
 public class CustomerDAO : ICustomerDAO
    {

        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

        private TransactionTemplate tt;

        public IPlatformTransactionManager  TransactionManager
        {
            set { tt = new TransactionTemplate(value); }
        }
 <snip/>


        public Customer find(string login) 
        {
            IList<Customer> customers;
            Object result = tt.Execute(delegate(ITransactionStatus status) //line 42
            {
                var transaction = status.Transaction;

                  var session = this.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
                  //var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
                  try
                  {
                      customers = session.CreateQuery("from Technolog.Rma.Business.Domain.Customer Customer where Customer.Login=?")
                          .SetParameter(0, login)
                          .List<Customer>();

                      if (customers.Count > 0)
                      {
                          return customers[0];
                      }
                  }
                  catch
                  {

                  }
                  finally
                  {
                      if (session != null) session.Close();
                  }

                  return null;
              });


            return (Customer)result;

        }
```

The error I'm now getting is

```
Server Error in '/RMA' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AdoTransaction'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AdoTransaction'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AdoTransaction'.]
   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() +425
   Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.DoCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data.NHibernate\Data\NHibernate\HibernateTransactionManager.cs:579
   Spring.Transaction.Support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.ProcessCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data\Transaction\Support\AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cs:853
   Spring.Transaction.Support.TransactionTemplate.Execute(TransactionDelegate transactionMethod) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data\Transaction\Support\TransactionTemplate.cs:159
   Technolog.Rma.Business.Repositories.CustomerDAO.find(String login) in C:\work\samplemvc\src\Technolog.Rma.Business\Repositories\CustomerDAO.cs:42
   _dynamic_Technolog.Rma.Business.Repositories.CustomerDAO.find(Object , Object[] ) +147
   Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeMethod.Invoke(Object target, Object[] arguments) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicMethod.cs:156
   Spring.Aop.Framework.DynamicMethodInvocation.InvokeJoinpoint() in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Aop\Aop\Framework\DynamicMethodInvocation.cs:100
   Spring.Dao.Support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation) in c:\_prj\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Data\Dao\Support\PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.cs:190
   CompositionAopProxy_33677284ca854c0b8c01a5b0ae0a0524.find(String login) +383
   Technolog.Rma.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index(Int32 page) in C:\work\samplemvc\src\Technolog.Rma.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:36
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +112
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above I followed the instructions for implementing osiv. I also found I was closing a session when I should have left it open thus causing a

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

My web.config file for using OSIV is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368

  Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core

    <resource uri="~/Config/propertyConfigurer.xml" />
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.MvcContextHandler, Spring.Web.Mvc3" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="dataFile" value="App_Data\data.db3" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="SessionFactory"/>
  </appSettings>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/propertyConfigurer.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/sessionFactory.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/mappers.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/repositories.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/controllers.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/scopedobjects.xml" />
      <resource uri="file://~/Config/utils.xml" />
    </context>
  </spring>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>

      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/> 

    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate32"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
    <handlers>
      <add name="SpringPageHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="SpringWebServiceHandler" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
      <add name="SpringContextMonitor" verb="*" path="ContextMonitor.ashx" type="Spring.Web.Support.ContextMonitor, Spring.Web"/>
    </handlers>
    -->
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.7.0" newVersion="4.0.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that references to osiv and spring WebSupportModule are in / to make it work in my dev environment and also in / to make the application work in IIS 7.5

I'm also using lazy loading in my views so osiv is the better solution. I showed the programmatic transaction control in my question because that's how far I had got with trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: +1 for posting your solution here; good to hear you got it to work

Answer (score 0):

You have configured a `TransactionManager`, but you are not using it. Before calling `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();`, try starting a transaction on your transaction manager. When using Spring's transaction management, you shouldn't explicitly use NHibernate's transaction support.

You can do this [programmatically](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-programmatic) or [declaratively](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#dtm); at this stage I'd try the programmatic approach first.

Comment: Hello Marijin, I've made changes so that the transaction are applied programmatically but they created a different error. I've modified my original post to show the changes I've made and the results I got. I'll do the transactions declaratively tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: Let spring do the session management for you, do not dispose the session yourself.

Comment: I made some changes, as per the spring documentation for OSIV [link](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-web) and also found I was closing a session in my CustomerDAO.find method which was casuing subsequent exceptions further on in the code. Thanks for your help Marijn.

Comment: Great you got it to work! IIRC osiv isn't required when using (programmatic or declarative) transaction management, but I might be mistaken here. If you post your solution as an answer, you can accept it to let everyone here know your problem was solved - and you might get some up votes too :)

Comment: Hello Marijn you're  right OSIV isn't required but it makes my code simpler. However I might need more fine grained transaction control so might revert to programmatic control as the need arises.